# JQuery Validate using addClassRules: What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've put together a snippet of code in ASP.NET MVC in which I'm trying to use the addClassRules methods of jQuery's validator.  From what I can tell I'm taking this straight of the examples on

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference

But the page is just submitted it doesn't show any errors.  I would like to use the "addClassRules" pattern for validation because I'm writing dynamic forms.

Here's my View.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>ValidateMyForm</title>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>        

        <input type="text" value="" name="customer1" class="customer" />
        <input type="text" value="" id="customer2" name="customer2" class="customer" />
        <input type="text" name="customer3" class="customer" />

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    <% } %>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // alias required to cRequired with new message
            $.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required, "Customer name required");
            // alias minlength, too
            $.validator.addMethod("cMinlength", $.validator.methods.minlength, $.format("Customer name must have at least {0} characters"));
            // combine them both, including the parameter for minlength
            $.validator.addClassRules("customer", { cRequired: true, cMinlength: 2 });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATED:  Fully functional code...**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>ValidateMyForm</title>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "demoform" }))
        { %>        

        <%: Html.TextBox("myTextBox", "", new {@class = "cRequired"}) %>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    <% } %>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $.validator.addClassRules("cRequired", { required: true });

            jQuery("#demoform").validate();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out that you MUST have the following line in the jQuery(document).ready() function as well.

```
jQuery("#demoform").validate();
```

"demoform" being the name of your Form element.  In my case (MVC) I gave it this name as followings...

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "demoform" })) { %>
```

Comment: Sweet deal! Glad you were able to figure it out. You should mark this as the answer for other users facing the same problem.

Comment: Thanks I will but SO forces me to wait 1 day:)  I've updated the question to show the complete working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Never used this validator before, but it looks like your syntax is a bit off. Also, you're not defining cRequired anywhere.

*Please note that none of the following has been tested.*

First You'll need to define cRequired:

```
$.validator.addMethod("cRequired", $.validator.methods.required,
  "Customer name required");
```

Next you'll need to add a validator to a class (where "YourClassName" is the class this should apply to.)

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("YourClassName", {
  cRequired: true
});
```

**OR**

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
 YourClassName: {
   cRequired: true
 }
});
```

You'll then need to add the class to your inputs:

```
<input id="txtOne" type="text" class="YourClassName">
<input id="txtTwo" type="text" class="YourClassName">
<input id="txtThree" type="text" class="YourClassName">
```

Hope this helps...

Sources:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addClassRules
- http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference

Comment: Thanks.  In my prev example I was thinking I could just refer to "required" as my rule.  Unfortunetly though this did not fix my problem.  But I have updated my example to use pretty much the exact code from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [jQuery validation plugin](http://www.salesplusplus.com/validatemyform-jquery-plugin-easy-form-validation/)